# Questions on PCA

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have a hard time understand the following statements below about PCA (normed or not normed).

a) the matrix to diagonalize is the matrix of linear correlations of original variables.
b) An illustrative variable is well represented on a factorial axis if its contribution is high on this axis.

It would be really helpful if someone could explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read the chapter for the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) in the book 'Linear Algebra' of Gilbert Strang. There's no other book that explains it more intuitively and clearly. The SVD and PCA have the same purpose in practical applications: Identifying the directions in which the data varies the most. In the end one tries to describe (approximate) the data with fewer dimensions by leaving out the dimensions that don't vary a lot.

I can't explain the whole SVD in detail. But here's the big picture: We'd like to decompose $A$ into $A=U\Sigma V^T$, where $U$ and $V$ have orthogonal columns and $\Sigma$ is just a diagonal matrix.

We know that $A^\top A$ is symmetric and thus diagonalizable. Since
$$
A^\top A = (U\Sigma V^\top)^\top U\Sigma V^\top
=V\Sigma U^\top U\Sigma V^\top = V\Sigma^2 V^T,
$$
by diagonalising $A^\top A$ and orthonormalising the eigenvectors of the decomposition we can get $V$ and $\Sigma$ from this process. The eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ are usually sorted in decreasing order. We then just use $A=U\Sigma V^\top \Longleftrightarrow AV=U\Sigma$ in order to determine $U$.

See also:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition  (Has some good pictures)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis

Answer (score -1):

PCA is kind of order reduction. You simply categorize the data to fewer dimensions in a way you can visualized such data. Imagine that you have list of 1000 kinds of win to pick one or two among such a list regards/ based on 5 or 6 or 7.... features. 
PCA analysis tool is a vital tool in such a case. PCA allows you to have a clear look on wins based on 2D dimensions (2 factors / 2 PCA's). Such factors/ PCAs take in accounts all the other features(factors) with various

To get more of the physical meaning of PCA, I highly recommend t check the following youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-Hb26agBFg

Reagrds to the statements you mentioned above:

a) the matrix to diagonalize is the matrix of linear correlations of original variables.

[U,D]=eigs(A'*A)   A'*A is the covariance matrix which is more or less (correlation).

b) An illustrative variable is well represented on a factorial axis if its contribution is high on this axis.

This means that high illustrative variable has high PCA.

Best regards